# Python / creating hours and minutes list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I want to create a list that contains hours and minutes. Every element in list has 30 minute between start and end.

```
times = ["9:00 - 9:30","9:30 - 10:00","10:00 - 10:30", "10:30 - 11:00","11:00 - 11:30",..........,"21:30 - 22:00"]
```

The list should start at 9:00 and ends at 22:00, so final element of list will be "21:30 - 22:00".

Is there any way to this in a short way?

Comment: How? thats the problem.@Alchimie

Comment: The `datetime` package may be helpful. Or simple indexing (for example, even for `x.00 - x:300`, odd for `y:30 - y+1:00`) to generate the desirable outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant way, but you could do this with a for loop:

```
times = []
for i in range(9, 22):
    times.append(f"{i}:00 - {i}:30")
    times.append(f"{i}:30 - {i+1}:00")
```

Output:

```
['9:00 - 9:30', '9:30 - 10:00', '10:00 - 10:30', '10:30 - 11:00', '11:00 - 11:30', '11:30 - 12:00', '12:00 - 12:30', '12:30 - 13:00', '13:00 - 13:30', '13:30 - 14:00', '14:00 - 14:30', '14:30 - 15:00', '15:00 - 15:30', '15:30 - 16:00', '16:00 - 16:30', '16:30 - 17:00', '17:00 - 17:30', '17:30 - 18:00', '18:00 - 18:30', '18:30 - 19:00', '19:00 - 19:30', '19:30 - 20:00', '20:00 - 20:30', '20:30 - 21:00', '21:00 - 21:30', '21:30 - 22:00']
```

Comment: This is Perfect. Thank you so much.@patmcb

Comment: Wouldn't using `range(9, 22)` be nicer than adding 9 everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

heres a pandas way to do it

```
>>> my_range = pandas.date_range("09:00","21:30",freq="30min")                                                        
>>> my_range.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "-" +  my_range.shift(1).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thank you.@Joran Beasley